# Using optim on a two-variable function

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am having trouble optimizing over a function with two parameters.

```
# Creating a corresponding mock data set
N=2000
x <- rnorm(N,0,1)
x <- cumsum(x)
n=length(x)

k=1

dx = rep(0,n-k)
for (i in k:(n - 1)){
  sumx = 0
  for (j in 0:k){
    sumx = sumx + (-1)^j*choose(k,j)*x[i-j+1]
  }
  dx[i-k+1] = sumx
}

vpk <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 10)
for (p in seq(from=1, to=10,by=1)) { 
  vpk[p*1] <- sum(abs(dx)^p)
}

vpk = data.frame(vpk);
names(vpk)='V1';
vpk$V2 = 1:10;
```

Now to my minimizing function

```
Rab <- function(a,b){
  g <- ifelse(a>0 & a<1-1/p & p >=b & b<=2, a*p,
              ifelse(a>0 & a<1-1/b & p< b & b<=2, -1+(a+1/b),
                     ifelse(a >= 1-1/pmax(p,b) & b<=2,-1+p,NA)))
} 

#p=1
suma <- function(a,b){
  sume=0
  for(p in seq(from=1,to=10, by=1)){
    sume = sume + (log(vpk$V1[p])/log(n^(-1))-outer(a,b,Rab))^2
  }
  return(sume)
}
```

The values I would like to minimize over is `a` and `b`, and the values for `a` and `b` is as follows:

```
a= seq(0.1,5,by=0.25)
b= seq(0,2,by=0.1)
```

Now I can plot the function with `a` and `b` as above, by first defining `z`

```
z <-suma(a,b)

persp(a,b,z, theta=-135, phi=45, ticktype='detailed')
image(a,b,z)
contour(a,b,z, add=T)
```

Here I can see that for the function to be minimized a should be near 0 and can lie between 0 and 2.

Now, what I want to do, is to minimize '`suma'`. This is where I have trouble. I've done:

```
optim(c(0.00001,1.5), suma)
```

But I guess I need to make `suma` a function of just one parameter to get this to work. Any help is appreciated! I've tried with `optim`, but I might want to try another package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function to this:

```
suma <- function(par){
  sume=0
  for(p in seq(from=1,to=10, by=1)){
    sume = sume + (log(vpk$V1[p])/log(n^(-1))-outer(par[1],par[2],Rab))^2
  }
  return(sume)
}
```

Package [optimx](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optimx/index.html) might be of interest to you.